Why is the area enclosed by a polar equation given by the definite integral of $\frac{1}{2}r^2$ with respect to $\theta$?
Suppose there is a polar equation $r = f(\theta)$. To find the area bound by the polar equation and the equations $\theta = \beta$ and $\theta = \alpha$ where $\beta > \alpha $, one must use $$\int_α^β \frac{1}{2}r^2 {d\theta} \tag{1}$$
I understand where the formula comes from, but why can't the area be approximated using right angled triangles with base r and height $\theta$ which would then give the expression $$\int_a^b \frac{1}{2}r {d\theta} \tag{2}$$
Why is (1) right while (2) is wrong ?

The right triangle ignores the circular segment in the approximation.

Yes, but as the right angles get smaller and smaller, wouldn't the error approach 0?

You probably mean "central angle," but regardless the answer is no.

$d\theta$ is not the height. $d\theta r$ is the height

Can anyone tell me how this formula comes?? I have seen that it is used in calculating the area of folium of Descartes. I haven't studied polar integration yet, can I get a hint from where this expression comes??

Here is a way to see why & why not :
WHY :
When $r$ is varying with $\theta$ & we consider some very small change $\delta\theta$ , then we assume $r$ is not changing much.
The arc is then $r\delta\theta$ & hence the area of the Shaded Sector is $\frac{1}{2} \times r \times r\delta\theta = \frac{1}{2} r^2\delta\theta$ [[ very much like a triangle ]]
We want to integrate this between the limits.

WHY NOT :
When we take Base $r$ & Height $\theta$ , or rather Height $\delta\theta$ , we are not accounting for the increase in arc length due to radius.
We are taking Height $\delta\theta$ occurring at the Unit Circle , not at the radius $r$.
You can check that by using my Picture & then marking the arc of length $\delta\theta$
No matter where & what you mark , you will not get the Shaded Area.

Height is not $\theta$, it is dimensionless.
For a strip from $\theta$ to $\theta+\mathrm d\theta$, you can approximate it by a right triangle with height $r$ and base $r\,\mathrm d\theta$ (not $\mathrm d\theta$). So, the area is
$$\frac12\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}r^2\,\mathrm d\theta$$
Hope this helps. :)
